# Enabling vim undo history in Cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have an install of Cygwin on a Windows 10 machine. I am trying to enable undo history in `vim` so that it is remembered between `vim` instances. At the moment everything is forgotten after closing the editor. My `.exrc` includes the following:

```
set undofile
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo
set undolevels=1000
set undoreload=10000
```

I did have a problem with `.swp` files not being opened correctly. Apparently the directory didn't exist and `vim` wasn't able to create one itself. However, `$HOME/.vim/undo` definitely exists:

```
drwx------+ 1 xxx Domänen-Benutzer 0 May 18 14:19 tmp
drwx------+ 1 xxx Domänen-Benutzer 0 May 18 14:20 undo
```

I have tried following [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/undo-multiple-changes-in-cygwins-vim) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/are-cygwin-vim-commands-different-than-normal-vim), including setting the following:

```
set nocompatible
```

I have also tried following [this advice](https://codeyarns.com/2010/01/14/vim-unable-to-open-swap-file/) and set:

```
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo
```

However, it still does not work. Any other ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Edit a file (perhaps with `vim --noplugin`), `:set verbose=1`, and `:w`. If it were working it would say `Writing undo file: {filename}`. What does yours say?

Comment: Nothing. Simply `"test" 5L, 29C written`

Comment: It's not even trying? When you do `:set` everything there looks as expected (esp. `undofile` and `undodir`)? What happens when you try to write to the undodir directly, e.g. `:exec 'w ' . &undodir . '/tmp.txt'`

Comment: Nothing. It returns with no output and the file is not written. But then `:echo 'something'` doesn't do anything either.